# Is there any way to import a .xlsx saved on the gdrive to a gsheet with python?

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets

Unfortunately, I don't have any code to post here. 
I tried some things but none of them really work. I want to automatically import an excel (that gets refreshed every 2 hours) to a gsheet. 
I couldn't figure out how to do it with headless browsers, or with the g-suite API. 
The only thing I found was a site, but that doesn't work for me, because it's for a company and I cannot get permission to do that. 
Does anybody have any idea whatsoever? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You cannot directly import a .xlsx into Google Sheets

But you can:

1. Convert the .xlsx to a Google Spreadsheet

   - If the file is already on your drive, the easiest way to convert it would be with the [Drive v2 method Files: Copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy) specifying `convert` `true`.

Sample:

```
service.files().copy(fileId=file_id,convert=true, body={"title": "MyNewGoogleSheet"}).execute()
```

- If the excel file is on your local disc, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types_) provides a sample how to import it to a Google type in Python, you just need to change the mimeType from `'text/csv'` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

  2. Copy-paste a sheet / range from the converted spreadsheet into your already existing spreadsheet.
- Use for it a method of the Sheets API, like e.g. [spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo)

Sample:

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'My Report',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/report.csv',
                        mimetype='text/csv',
                        resumable=True)
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

Comment: is there any way you could provide a small code example on the above?
The .xlsx file sits on the drive.