# How do I solve a Google Sheet API error in Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using the following code to download a Gsheet into Python.  It works for some sheets but not all.

```
import pickle
import os.path
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def gsheet_api_check(SCOPES):
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds


def pull_sheet_data(SCOPES,SPREADSHEET_ID,RANGE_NAME):
    creds = gsheet_api_check(SCOPES)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    #result = copy_file(service, SPREADSHEET_ID, copy_title)
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        rows = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
        data = rows.get('values')
        print("COMPLETE: Data copied")
        return data
```

On the sheets that cause an error I recieve the following msg:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1bI_X2ssOj9gTYnKsa_CDajYP0FcFMr0E/values/3-7-14days?alt=json returned "This operation is not supported for this document">
```

I believe the error could be because the original spreadsheet was copied from a .xlsx format.  I'm having trouble implementing a copy function to get around this error.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
I changed the functions so that it incorporate both Drive API and Sheets API

    def gsheet_api_check(SCOPES):
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds

def drive_api_check(SCOPES):
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('drivecredentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds

def pull_sheet_data(Sheets_SCOPES, Drive_SCOPES,SPREADSHEET_ID,RANGE_NAME):
    sheet_creds = gsheet_api_check(Sheets_SCOPES)
    drive_creds = drive_api_check(Drive_SCOPES)
    sheet_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=sheet_creds)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=drive_creds)
    drive_service.files().copy(fileId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body={"mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}).execute()
    #service.files().copy(fileId=SPREADSHEET_ID,convert=true, body={"title": "specifyName"}).execute()
    sheet = sheet_service.spreadsheets()
    copy_title = 'temp'
    #result = copy_file(service, SPREADSHEET_ID, copy_title)
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, 
   range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        rows = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, 
   range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
        data = rows.get('values')
        print("COMPLETE: Data copied")
        return data
```

Now I get the following error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1bI_X2ssOj9gTYnKsa_CDajYP0FcFMr0E/copy?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

Comment: Do you mean that the document that you request with `SPREADSHEET_ID` is a .xlsx file? Or is it a Google Sheets file to which an .xlsx file has been converted? How did you perform the conversion?

Comment: it was an excel which Google sheets converted.  For some reason some of the files work file but some give that error

Comment: How did you convert the files?

Comment: It was sent to my gmail and I opened it automatically in gSheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Before using the Sheets API on an Excel file, you need to convert it to a Google Spreadsheet

Opening an Excel file with Google sheets is not equivalent to converting it.

You can convert the file programamtically, e.g. with the [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) method of the Drive API.

Sample request:

```py
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
service.files().copy(fileId=ID_OF_THE_EXCEL_FILE, body={"mimeType"="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}).execute()
```

Use the `id` of the **converted** file as `SPREADSHEET_ID` for your request.

Comment: Thanks very much but will this work with v4 of Gsheets API.  v3 is being depreciated

Comment: Please do not confuse Drive API with Sheets API. Sheets API v3 is indeed deprecated, but as for Drive API - v3 is the newest version. You can even do the conversion with Drive API v2 (not deprecated neither)  as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873192/is-there-any-way-to-import-a-xlsx-saved-on-the-gdrive-to-a-gsheet-with-python/60882384#60882384). Note that if you called you sheet service `service`, you should give the drive service another name, e.g. `driveService = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)`

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have run into more trouble after adding both the Drive and Sheets API.  See my update above

Comment: You need to enable the scope for the Drive API in your GCP console, as well as assign both scopes to the variable`SCOPES`. Afer this, you need to delete your token file to trigger new authorization flow.

Comment: i get an error:  Cell In[117], line 22
    service.files().copy(fileId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, body={"mimeType"="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}).execute()
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?

edit: i think i fixed it ... but now getting an error : AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'files'