# Converting xlsx to Google Sheets in Jupyter

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, jupyter-notebook, xlsx

I'm trying to open a xlsx file from Google Drive as a Google Sheets file in Jupyter.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'gs_credentials.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'someidhere'
RANGE = 'somerangehere'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range=RANGE).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

this script work for reading data from a Google Sheet, but i have one that's saved as xlsx. Is there a way to convert it? I found a couple answers that went something like:

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
service.files().copy(fileId=ID_OF_THE_EXCEL_FILE, body={"mimeType"="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}).execute()
```

from [How do I solve a Google Sheet API error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783192/how-do-i-solve-a-google-sheet-api-error-in-python)

but this doesn't seem work for me. (i think the syntax is broken... tried to fix it, but couldn't figure it out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Syntax error:

You are in the right direction on the converting xlsx to spreadsheet.Try changing the `=` to `:` in `mimeType`.

Correct syntax should be `body={"mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}`

After converting the `xlsx file` to `google spreadsheet` you can then use the `spreadsheet service` to obtain the values on the file. Please see sample code below.

### Your Code should look like this:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'gs_credentials.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'someidhere'
RANGE = 'somerangehere'

# Build the services
service_drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
service_sheets = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)


# Converting xlsx file to google spreadsheet

xlsx_file = service_drive.files().copy(fileId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, body= 
{"mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}).execute()

# extracting the new converted spreadsheet Id
new_id = xlsx_file.get('id', [])

# Getting the values using the spreadsheet service
result =   service_sheets.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=new_id,range = RANGE).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

#converting values to dataframe using pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df
```

### My sample Code on Google Colaboratory:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.colab import auth
from google.auth import default
import pandas as pd

auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()

# Edits starts here from your existing code
# Build the services
service_drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
service_sheets = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# xlsx file Id
file_id = 'Id here'
range = "Range here"

# Converting xlsx file to google spreadsheet

xlsx_file = service_drive.files().copy(fileId=file_id, body={"mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}).execute()

# extracting the new converted spreadsheet Id
new_id = xlsx_file.get('id', [])

# Getting the values using the spreadsheet service
result = service_sheets.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=new_id,range = range).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

#converting values to dataframe using pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df
```

**Note:** Authentication may differ from you since I am running this code on `google colab`

### Output:

[image]

### References:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

Comment: i just tried but wasn't able to install google.colab on my Jupyter notebook. It was doing fine for a while, but then exploded into a giant error %\ ... Ending with "error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output] note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of pandas"

Comment: There is no need to install google colab, just run the code from the previous ide you used. I just stated that I ran my notebook on google colab since the authentication is different from yours based on the code you have provided.

Comment: i'm running it in Jupyter and it said "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'". Oh ok, i just copy pasted your code.

Comment: with `service_drive = build('sheets', 'v3', credentials=creds)` i get an error : `HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1OQw4HvGnCi8gycVOvo4XdVIjsawnretN/copy?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}]">`

 And with `service_drive = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)` it's `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'files'`

Comment: I updated my answer above and added what your code should look like. Please let me know if you are still having errors. Thanks

Comment: omg that google.colab attempted install completely nuked my jupyter %\ .... trying to reinstall all the proper dependencies now ... will let you know once i get it working again

Comment: I am sorry for that, I should have added that there is no need for the google.colab install on your end. I have updated my answer above on what your code should look like on your end.Please let me know if you are still having errors. Thank you

Comment: ok, i think Jupyter is fixed. That was scary. But still getting that `HttpError 403` error. Weird. I added the service-account to that xlsx file and everything, just like with the google sheet file. Not sure why it's complaining about permissions. The error starts on this line `xlsx_file = service_drive.files().copy(fileId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, body= 
 {"mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"}).execute()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251449/discussion-between-george-and-raksha).